# Освобождение памяти Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, память

В программе есть mutableListOfBalls. Когда Ball выйдет за границы поля, я хочу удалить его. Я удаляю его из массива(меняю местами с последним и удаляю последний), но после того как сгенерировалось и удалилось много Ball, то приложение начинает тормозить, хотя в listOfBalls пустой. Думаю, что, когда я удаляю Ball из списка, то он не удаляется из памяти. Действительно ли проблема в памяти, и можно ли как-то удалить объект моего класса(может нужно написать деструктор?)?

Comment: Если причина именно в объектах ball, то это значит что кто-то держит ссылку на удаляемый объект. Если используется JVM, а не Kotlin Native, то утечку памяти можно найти посредством jvisualvm. Это профайлер, он позволяет в любой момент получить дамп памяти, в котором надо поискать удаляемые объекты, если они присутсвуют то там же можно увидеть кто на них держит ссылку. Если это разработка под Android, то я не знаю можно ли использовать jvisualvm против него, но для Android тоже должны быть профайлеры.

Comment: @Александр-Березовский Какие признаки у утечки памяти? Сначала мое приложение жутко лагало + вылетало, потом я написал свой LinkedList и теперь приложение просто вылетает при долгом использовании. Если не утечка, то на что похоже?

Comment: При использовании профайлера первый признак это постоянный рост использования кучи (heap). Нормальное поведение это пила, зубцы "пилы" создают постоянно создающиеся и удаляющиеся объекты. Не знаю где утечка, но мой опыт говорит что утечки возникают у тех кто используется HashMap и HashSet против мутабельных объектов у которых переопределен hashCode.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему я решил. В kotlin есть объекты, которые JVM не может удалить сама => они будут накапливаться бесконечно и не очищаться. Это исправляется тем, что мы можем заново проинициализировать такие объекы и использовать их снова. Простой пример тут http://www.libgdx.ru/2013/10/memory-management.html . Я же  просто создал listOfDeletedBalls и вместо создания новых объектов ball брал старые deleted экземпляры и менял у них параметры.

Comment: Непонятно, причем тут Котлин. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB